# Buffer app using twisted/asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted, python-asyncio

I have a simple app that receives data and must push it to another service in batches.

How can I implement it using twisted or asyncio?

Currently, I have next code using twisted:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, endpoints
from twisted.protocols import basic


class FirehoseProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.data.append(line)

    def push_to_firehose(self):
        pass  # TODO


class EchoFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
    protocol = FirehoseProtocol


endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:5001").listen(EchoFactory())

reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what defines a batch.  If we assume a number of lines defines a batch:

```
def lineReceived(self, line):
    self.data.append(line)
    if len(self.data) == batch_size:
        self.push_to_firehose()
```

Comment: Exactly, batch means N lines, where N is dynamic and will be calculated depending on line sizes.But I assume that it will block receiving new lines, right? The app needs to be pretty highload, so it must serve at least 300 records per second.

Comment: You assume that what will block?  APIs in Twisted won't block.  That's the point of Twisted.